# How to backup from Db2 (on Cloud) to cloud storage?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage

We have an application on Bluemix and use the Db2 on Cloud service (http://www.ibm.com/analytics/us/en/technology/cloud-data-services/db2-on-cloud/).

Everything works now, but we would like to have backups in place. Because we are talking about a cloud solution, I was wondering whether some backup logic would already be implemented so we don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is support in that sense that you could use DB2 Backup tools and store that data on cloud storage like Amazon S3 or SoftLayer Object Storage. See this entry in the [DB2 on Cloud docs](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/DB2OnCloud/index.html#remoteSettings) for more details. There are also tools to manage the remote storage.

Syntax would like here:

```
backup db <database-name>
    to db2remote://<alias>//<storage-path>
```

I have created a [blog entry to discuss how Db2 (including the former dashDB) can be combined with Cloud Object Storage](http://blog.4loeser.net/2017/08/combining-db2-and-cloud-object-storage.html). It covers the command `CATALOG STORAGE ACCESS ALIAS` and what needs to be done to get it up and running.